# Selenium assert new line error

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm quite new to selenium and I was trying to test a given feature of my application. I've got a multiline input in which I enter the following:

> bla bla bla
>
> foo bar

Which, once read by selenium is translated to

`bla bla bla\r\nfoo bar`

in the .feature file, i've got the following scenario:

```
Scenario: Someone does some typing
   When I open the input
   Then I can read
   | Input                  |
   | bla bla bla\r\nfoo bar |
```

When I debug the test, the value from the table viewed from the debbuger is:

```
bla bla bla\\r\nfoo bar
           ^ note the extra backslash
```

I don't understand from where this backslash is comming from. Any clue ?

Code :

```
namespace Selenium.SpecFlow.Steps
{
    [Binding]
    public class WorkflowUrgenceSteps
    {
      private readonly OpenConsutationPage _openConsutationPage;

      [...]

      [Then(@"I can read")]
      public void ThenICanRead(Table table)
      {
        var expectedInfos = table.CreateInstance<NewUrgentRequest>();

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedInfos.Input, _openConsutationPage.GetInput());
      }


    }
}
```

And

```
namespace Selenium.Pages
{
    public class OpenConsutationPage : PageBase
    {
        public string GetInput()
        {
            var input = By.CssSelector("blockquote>p>b");
            Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(input));
            return Driver.FindElement(input).Text;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: any code from steps

Comment: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/789

Comment: It looks like something is trying to escape the first backslash but doesn't escape the second for some reason. Have you tried running in the debugger and examining the string at multiple steps? You should be able to at least find out when it appears.